# What is a term to describe data where the mode represents a large proportion of all observations?

Tags: mode, central-tendency

Below are some histograms of continuous variables, where 20-50% of all observations fall on the mode.

Are there any terms to describe data that exhibit this unusual concentration of observations on the mode?

[image]
[image]
[image]